# How do I automatically process all fields from a form and pass them into php?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, forms

How do I get all the data from the form?

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    action: 'form_handler_subscribtion',
     // 
  },
  success: function ( success ) {

  },
  fail: function( fail) {

  }
});
```

I can get the data by specifying each field manually, but I would like to get it automatically. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.serialize()`
[Official doc](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Example:

```
var data = $("#idform").serialize(); 
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: data,
  success: function ( success ) {

  },
  fail: function( fail) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        action: $('YOUR FORM ID').serialize(),
         // 
      },
      success: function ( success ) {
    
      },
      fail: function( fail) {
    
      }
    });
```